# FFTW3 linking in C

Tags: c, macos, linker, linker-errors, fftw

I can't link fftw3 library (latest on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5). I have a sample-code from the [developers](http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html) here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </usr/local/include/fftw3.h>


int main()
    {
    int N;

    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;


    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);


    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */


    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);
}
```

I don't expect it to make sense. At this point I was it just to compile.

1) I have followed the manual and tried:

gcc -lm -lfftw3 FFT.c -o FFT

gcc FFT.c -I$/usr/local/include/ -L$/usr/local/include/ -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT

and many other variations.

2) When I open /usr/local/include/, I don't really see a libfftw3-file, however, I have libfftw3.la in /Applications/fftw-3.3.7. Hence, I have also tried

gcc FFT.c -I$/Applications/fftw-3.3.7. -L$/Applications/fftw-3.3.7. -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT

3) I have tried to copy libfftw3.la into /usr/local/include/ and pass option (1) to the terminal again...

All the same error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L$/Applications/fftw-3.3.7.'
ld: library not found for -lfftw3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please, help! Don't know where to look any more. The manual is very high level for me and doesn't seem to cover these issues extensively/completely.

Comment: `-L$/Applications/fftw-3.3.7`. What's the `$` doing there?

Comment: `$` is a problem here. Do: `gcc FFT.c -L/Applications/fftw-3.3.7. -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre just tried: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/fftw-3.3.7.'
ld: library not found for -lfftw3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: How did you install fftw3. Did you build it from source and do a `make install` or did you use package manager?

Comment: I assume this is MacOS

Comment: @ Michael Petch I used make install

Comment: the trailing "." is suspicious as well. Try to locate `/Applications`. Maybe you meant `~/Applications` ? we cannot log on your machine to check that. note that the linker is super-nice by warning you about that. I remember linkers not giving a damn about the directory existing or not.

Comment: (well, we can but we forbid ourselves to do such things :))

Comment: @Michael Petch I have downloaded the software from the link in my post, saved the folder in applications and used 1) ./configure 2) make 3) make install

Comment: No 8(  really stupid... ohhhh8*((((( Is there a way to fix it at this point or I should re-install.

Comment: no, format your hard drive NOW! (don't!). Can you check the directories I pointed out? do you have `/Applications` ? or `~/Applications` existing?

Comment: You usually don't build from the Applications folder. You can do that from  a folder in your accoutn director. Most default ./configure scripts will generate Makefiles that place the installation under `/usr/local` .when you finally do the `sudo make install`

Comment: okay so `gcc FFT.c -I$/usr/local/include/ -L$/usr/local/include/ -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT` is also wrong: should be `gcc FFT.c -L/usr/local/include/ -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT` but isn't that dir included by default?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre haha =?  like you've corrected, lol X))))

Comment: @MsTais. glad you like it. Cannot reproduce your issue. I've got to buy a mac first. Check your directories, good luck.

Comment: @Michael Petch I have done sudo make install, it looked like it was right this time. Then I ran gcc FFT.c -L/usr/local/include/ -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT, and this time it sees the directory, but it still doesn't see the library.

Comment: @Michael Petch So its like gcc FFT.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT    ?

Comment: @Michael Petch IT WORKED!!!!!! yeiiiii! Post it as the answer, I'll give you points!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question sounds like you haven't properly installed the `fftw3` software. Your comments suggest you built from source with:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

The first two commands are okay. The problem is `make install`. `make install` unlike the other two commands must be run as root privileges to gain write access to the directories it needs. What you should do is:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This will elevate `make install` to root privileges after you put in your account password.

By default most configure scripts place library and include files under `/usr/local` . Usually includes are in `/usr/local/include` and libraries in `/usr/local/lib` . To compile you should be able to specify includes with `-I` and libraries with `-L` like this:

```
gcc FFT.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 -lm -o FFT
```